# xmlParser parse lead to crash in iOS8, but work fine in iOS 7?

Tags: ios, parsing, crash

Running on simulator,[xmlParser parse] can lead to crash in iOS 8,but work fine in iOS7. I can't find any difference between iOS 7 and iOS 8 about the NSXMLParser.

The related:

```
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:xmlFilePath];
NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
[xmlParser setDelegate:self];
BOOL success = [xmlParser parse];//crash at this line.
```

Comment: what error? stacktrace?

Comment: please look the link:http://pan.baidu.com/s/1mgFSRjU to find more information.

Comment: can you let your app to crash by removing all breaking points, especially the exception break point

Comment: Please do this, close Xcode, open the simulator, open your app, it crashes, open your spotlight and search for "console". console app opens, there should be a crash log for this app, see what it says

Comment: are you sure that xmlfilepath is not nil and also the contents are fetched properly are you able to print the contents of the file ?

Comment: ibsystem_sim_trace.dylib + 19966 [CAC00A59-2A60-3F7F-9225-8FF531FC03BC]: 0x4
Aug 13 11:50:28 limings-mini.line6.crp MobilePOD[4445]: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'NSXMLParser does not support reentrant parsing.'
 *** First throw call stack:
 (
  0   CoreFoundation                      0x0381cdf6 __exceptionPreprocess + 182
  1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x02d9b837 objc_exception_throw + 44

Comment: is it all being called and executed on main thread ? nsxmlparser doc says it is thread safe as long as it only being used via one thread

Comment: I don't sure if it is being called and executed on main thread.How to verify?

Comment: I experience another type of exception in XML parser in iOS 8. I am getting message sent to deallocated string happening in the parser code. Also works fine on iOS 7. Apparently it is all messed up.

Answer (score 1):

In IOS 8 NSXMLParser does not support reentrant parsing.I am pretty sure the crash that leads at the line you specified is due to the reentrant parsing (i.e setting delegate within delegate methods of NSXMLParser). t[ake a look at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25363560/ios8-nsxmlparser-crash)

Hope it helps.

Comment: I had fixed the bug using the method as you said.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your XML does not contain zero sized non-breakable space UTF-8 symbol (also called utf encoding signature)  with the code xFEFF; This symbol in the attribute value leads to the iOS8 parser string deallocation error and crash. To get rid of this string in PHP backend use:

```
$char = mb_convert_encoding('&#xFEFF;', 'UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES');
$xml = str_replace(array($char, '&#FEFF;'),'',$xml);
```