# NSXMLParser on iOS8 - NSXMLParser does not support reentrant parsing

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, nsxmlparser, nsxmlparserdelegate

I have NSXMLParser problem, and i tried [iOS8 NSXMLParser crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25363560/ios8-nsxmlparser-crash) this topic, but i really did not get the solution.

I am creating another NXSMLParser delegate and setting its delegate in another class.

Could you please tell me what to do exactly, step by step? I am so confused.

Here is my code;

These lines of codes are inside the STXMLParser

```
   STXMLParser2 *stXMLParser2 = [[STXMLParser2 alloc]init];    

    stXMLParser2.xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:responseLoader.xmlData];
    [stXMLParser2.xmlParser setDelegate:self];
    [stXMLParser2.xmlParser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:YES];
    [stXMLParser2.xmlParser parse];
```

Comment: I think I've got a similar issue, but I'm using Swift. the parser crash at the time I call .parse() on it

Answer (score 16):

You can try this code:

```
dispatch_queue_t reentrantAvoidanceQueue = dispatch_queue_create("reentrantAvoidanceQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
    dispatch_async(reentrantAvoidanceQueue, ^{
        STXMLParser2 *stXMLParser2 = [[STXMLParser2 alloc]init];    
        stXMLParser2.xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:responseLoader.xmlData];
        [stXMLParser2.xmlParser setDelegate:self];
        [stXMLParser2.xmlParser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:YES];
        [stXMLParser2.xmlParser parse];
    });
    dispatch_sync(reentrantAvoidanceQueue, ^{ });
```

Comment: @JackSolomon If you are using a bunch of different `NSXMLParser` instances, you need to fix the case where you're calling `parse` for an `NSXMLParser` in a delegate callback from another `NSXMLParser`. This answer didn't fix my problem until I figured that little bit out.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same error and it turned out that the problem was due to calling a UI update in the `func parserDidEndDocument(parser: NSXMLParser)` which does not run on the main thread.  After forcing the UI update in that function to run on the main queue, the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem recently but it turned out that I had an exception in one of my delegates (KVO problem) and once I fixed that the reentracy error went away. So it might be worth to look for something else if you don't have an obvious multithreading or multiinstance problem.